# Some links not clickable at certain widths - bizarre issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, responsive-design

I'm building a simple list website using Bootstrap 2.3.1.

It's been up and running for the past few weeks and I haven't had a complaint but I've only just noticed something horribly wrong.

At certain widths, certain links aren't clickable. They still appear, but you cannot click them.

I've only spotted this as I've just included a small alert message that can be dismissed via a cross button, only to realise that at particular widths, it cannot be closed.

I've tried going through my code, removing anything I thought might be the issue and checking to see if it works, but to no avail. Unfortunately, the error (whatever the error is) seems to have been around for a while and thus I cannot for the life of me pinpoint where it is.

So I know people are going to be annoyed about this, but the only thing I can do is offer my entire site and hope someone can work out the issue.

For example: @1920px wide, everything works perfectly. @1060px wide, all hell breaks loose and most of the links don't work. Then @1024px wide, it all works again. Really weird.

Github repo: https://github.com/mildrenben/webdesignrepo

Thanks to anyone that helps in advance!

Edit: Only seems to be happening in chrome